# I am getting CORS error on ASP.NET MVC Web API app on account of LINQ

Tags: asp.net

I have CORS enabled in WebApi.config: allowing any header, method and origin

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {            
        // Web API routes
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();            
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Request Model

```
    public class PagingRequest
    {
         public int Start { get; set; }
         public int Length { get; set; }
         public int Draw { get; set; }
         public string Extra_search { get; set; }
         public List<Order> Order { get; set; }
         public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
         public Search Search { get; set; }
    }
```

The Controller Method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/users")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUsersList(PagingRequest pagingRequest)
    {
        try
        {
            var pagedUsersList = new UserService().GetUsersPendingActivation(pagingRequest);
            return Ok(pagedUsersList);

        }
        catch (System.Exception x)
        {
            Logger.Error(x);
            return Ok(new Page<UserViewModel>(new List<UserViewModel>()));
        }
   
    }
```

Service method

The problem I have is, Changing the m.Active" == true produces CORS error. I have tried removing the filter in LINQ and it works fine, but I need to filter out the data.

```
    public Page<UserViewModel> GetUsersPendingActivation(PagingRequest request){
       var unorderedList = entities.User.Where(
             m => (m.Active == null || m.Active == false )
             && m.AccountType != "Personal");
      return PaginateData(unorderedList, request);           
    }
```

Method that paginates my data. When debugging, I can see the data being retrieved, when response gets to client, I see CORS error.

```
     private Page<UserViewModel> PaginateData(IOrderedQueryable<User> data, PagingRequest request)
    {
        var filteredResults = data.Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length)
            .ToList();

        var userList = filteredResults.Select(user => new UserViewModel
        {
            /*setting other properties*/
            EncryptedId = ParameterEncryption.Encrypt(user.UserId.ToString())
        })
            .ToList();

        return new Page<UserViewModel>(userList)
        {
            recordsFiltered = data.Count(),
            recordsTotal = data.Count(),
            draw = request.Draw
        };
    }
```

Comment: You showed us a Linq query. Where is that called from? You're only showing us part of the picture.

Comment: @mason, i have edited origin post and added a bit more detail

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with CORS. Please show the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve the issue. Indeed it had nothing to do with CORS, even though the error in the browser console indicated it as such.
The issue originated from a recursive reference when converting my model which has a parent - child relation to JSON.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).